# How to start with performance testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance-testing

I am working on the rails 3.1.1 and using socery 0.7.11 for authentication, i need to implement the performance testing where i can test following things

- Simulate 100 users signing on and off simultaneously
- Simulate 100 users adding new interests simultaneously.

I have go through the following links:

http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/08/14/performance-testing-rails-applications-how-to/

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html

And able to do following things

- created test folder with test_helper.rb
- created test/performance/login_test.rb
- created fixtures/users.yml

test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

/performance/login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest

  fixtures :users
  # Refer to the documentation for all available options
   self.profile_options = { :runs => 5, :metrics => [:wall_time, :memory],
                            :output => 'tmp/performance', :formats => [:flat] }

  def test_login
   post_via_redirect "http://bc.lvh.me/", :username => users(:youruser).username, :password => users(:youruser).password
#using lvh.me coz login page is on my subdomain
  end
end
```

fixtures/users.yml

```
one:
  username: eagleschasar12
  password: chaitanyA1#

two:
  username: eaglesmarktell12
  password: chaitanyA1#
```

when i run rake test:profile, i got following result

```
E
===============================================================================
Error: test_login(LoginTest)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column named password: INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "password", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('eagleschasar12', 'chaitanyA1#', '2012-06-15 06:43:01', '2012-06-15 06:43:01', 980190962)
```

So my questions are

- Why test command firing insert query?
- Do i need to write 100 records of users in fixture file to test the functionality?
- How to check session login/logoff?
- Also when i select interest types from db my user should logged in the system, so how can i test this scenario in performance testing?
- Does this tests run on webrick, which is my local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions in order as best I can. I'm sure others might give more complete answers for each one individually and they're welcome to, but I hope to get you started so you can know what to look for:



*1. Why test command firing insert query?*

Your insert queries are run from your fixtures. Personally I user FactoryGirl, but the logic is the same. When you run your fixture, it inserts that object into your database. That way you can do something like `fixture :user` and it will create a user for you without having to supply all the User object details every time. If you have 5 fixtures in your file, running something like `fixture :users` will create 5 entries (If someone can confirm this for Fixtures I'd be grateful, as I don't user fixtures).



*2. Do i need to write 100 records of users in fixture file to test the functionality?*

No you don't. You can use the [Faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to automatically create as many users (or anything else) as you want with random names, strings, etc. The documentation is [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/master/frames).



*3. How to check session login/logoff?*

When you create your session, you should be setting the `session[user_id]` variable, so you can test for that. Needless to say, on logoff (i.e. session destroy) you should be setting it to `nil`. In any case, when a session is created by setting the `session[:user_id]` variable, then you can access the session ID using `request.session_options[:id]`



*4. Also when i select interest types from db my user should logged in the system, so how can i test this scenario in performance testing?*

Before each test you should run a "test_log_in" function that logs in the test user you create. Then the tests that require a logged in user should pass. You should also create tests where without logging in the test user, and they should not perform the changes (or should not display the pages) that require a logged in user.



*5. Does this tests run on webrick, which is my local server?*

If that is the server you have installed in you Gemfile, that it will be used. It will work with whichever server you have installed.



You have asked a lot of questions in one question, so if you need more detail on the the answers I would recommend you ask each question in a different post with a more detail description on what you're looking for. That way your answers will not be broad like this one, but more specific.

Hope I at least gave you a good place to start from.

Comment: Yes, you are right next time i will take care of this(about asking single question), thanks a lot for giving me a direction